# Check checkbox when idItem is the same in both arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a two arrays. An array that is a set of images and an array that is a set of data.

Is there a way to check the checkbox when the IDItem in the two arrays are the same?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsm9do?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.html**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="margin-top:120px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of items; let  j = index;">
        <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
            <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
                        <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
            </div>
            <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting mdc-image-list__supporting">
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label">{{product.name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Info">
                    <dx-check-box (onValueChanged)="change($event);" [value]="false"></dx-check-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

**.TS**

```
items=[
  {
    ID:1,
    IDItem:1,
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/3.jpg",
   name:"name1"
},
  {
    ID:2,
    IDItem:2,
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/10.jpg",
   name:"name2"
},
  {
    ID:3,
    IDItem:3,
   image:"https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/2x3/6.jpg",
   name:"name3"
},
]

data=[  {
    ID:1,
    IDItem:1,
},
  {
    ID:2,
    IDItem:2,
},]

change(e){
  console.log(e)
}
```

[image]

In this case, IDItem 1 and 2 are present in the items and data arrays. Is there a way for these items to mark the checkbox as checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by making a function to check if the current `product.IDItem` is present in any of the objects in the `data` array, and if it is, set the `value` property of your checkbox to `true`.

**TS (ES2016+)**

```
isProductInData( productId ) {
   const dataIds = this.data.map( i => i.IDItem );
   return dataIds.includes( productId );
}
```

**TS (Pre-ES2016)**

```
isProductInData( productId ) {
   const dataIds = this.data.map( i => i.IDItem );
   return dataIds.indexOf( productId ) !== -1;
}
```

*This will return `true` if the `productId` you pass in exists as a `IDItem` in any object in the `this.data` array*

**HTML**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="margin-top:120px;padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let product of items; let  j = index;">
        <li class="mdc-image-list__item">
            <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
                        <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image">
            </div>
            <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting mdc-image-list__supporting">
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label">{{product.name}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="Info">
                    <dx-check-box (onValueChanged)="change($event);" 
                                  [value]="isProductInData( product.IDItem )">
                    </dx-check-box>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. It didn't work, there is an error in includes. I forgot to put the demo in the post, I already updated it and you can test my code, thanks!

Comment: No problem, and thanks for the demo :) The approach does work, but I have amended my answer to also include an approach for earlier versions of JavaScript in case .includes() is not valid for your use case

Comment: Absolutely perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: I was trying to implement the code in my project, but when running the function isProductInData the function change () is always activated :( How can I prevent this? I made a console.log (productId) and got a large list of values, it has the do with that?

Comment: Are you able to modify the objects in the `items` array? You could add an extra key called 'defaultValue' to your items objects and instead of calling `isProductInData()` from your HTML, you could call it during the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. Something like `this.items.map( i => i.defaultValue = this.isProductInData(i.IDItem) )`. Then you simply need to say `[value]=product.defaultValue` in your HTML instead.

Comment: I tried this way, but the [value] does not assume the value :(

Comment: Everything is impeccable and the demo has no problems. In the project, it executes the function when receiving the value in [value]